# Angular js. Parse json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Im trying to parse this chunk of json with no good result. Below is how my json looks like. I want to be able to do ng-repeat on all attributes so that i can render for example "Content" and "Title" inside a div.

JSON:

```
{
    "Hits": [{
            "Content": "Lorem ipsum",
            "Id": "Lorem ipsum",
            "IllustratingImage120Url": "Lorem ipsum",
            "SearchPublishDate": "Lorem ipsum",
            "SearchUpdateDate": "Lorem ipsum",
            "Section": "Lorem ipsum",
            "Title": "Lorem ipsum",
            "Url": "Lorem ipsum"
        }, {
            "Content": "Lorem ipsum",
            "Id": "Lorem ipsum",
            "IllustratingImage120Url": "Lorem ipsum",
            "SearchPublishDate": "Lorem ipsum",
            "SearchUpdateDate": "Lorem ipsum",
            "Section": "Lorem ipsum",
            "Title": "Lorem ipsum",
            "Url": "Lorem ipsum"
        }
    }]
}
```

So i load the json with a service and set it to:

```
$scope.result = result.data;
```

Wich returns the josn, no problem. But i want to do ng-repeat on its attributes. But the whole json gets rendered. I only want to render the attribute "Content".

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="Content in result">{{ Content }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: $scope.result.Hits might contain the actual array you are looking for ?

Comment: `{{Content.Content}}`

Answer (score 0):

Because it just json, you can access the properties like so:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in result.Hits">{{ item.Content }}</li>
</ul>
```

See [plnk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rp3T4KQn6LzmJLR1lM1R?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="r in result.Hits">{{ r.Content }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in result.Hits">{{ value.Content }}</li>
</ul>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app",  []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.result = {
"Hits": [
{
  "Content": "Lorem ipsum",
  "Id": "Lorem ipsum",
  "IllustratingImage120Url": "Lorem ipsum",
  "SearchPublishDate": "Lorem ipsum",      
  "SearchUpdateDate": "Lorem ipsum",
  "Section": "Lorem ipsum",
  "Title": "Lorem ipsum",
  "Url": "Lorem ipsum"
},
{
  "Content": "Lorem ipsum",
  "Id": "Lorem ipsum",
  "IllustratingImage120Url": "Lorem ipsum",
  "SearchPublishDate": "Lorem ipsum",      
  "SearchUpdateDate": "Lorem ipsum",
  "Section": "Lorem ipsum",
  "Title": "Lorem ipsum",
  "Url": "Lorem ipsum"
}
  ]
};
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
     <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in result.Hits">{{ value.Content }}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have an Array contained within a JSON Object.

Please try

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="Content in result.Hits">{{ Content.Content }}</li>
</ul>
```